# Making an http request using NodeJS and access the returned cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, axios

I am querying a remote API using NodeJS. I am currently using Axios to make the request, but I am willing to use another package if required.

Using NodeJS, I make a request to a remote API.

```
Axios.post("http://remote.api/getCookie")
  .then(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
```

The API returns a number of cookies (this can be seen in the spec, and when I test it in a browser). How can I access these cookies from the value returned by Axios.

Comment: i can't get what you want? you mean to do this call from the browser then use the response to set the browser's cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Just get them from the `Set-Cookie` header:

```
Axios.post("http://<url>").then(response => {
  const cookies = response.headers["set-cookie"];
  // do whatever you want
}
```

You can then parse the header by yourself or use a library like [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) or [set-cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-cookie-parser)